Does the ratio of ingredients change in shirred eggs as the overall amount goes up?
My recipe for shirred eggs consists of 24 eggs, 2t salt, ½ cup melted butter, 2 cups milk.
I stretched that recipe to 30 eggs and slightly increased other ingredients. Results were great.
Then I bumped up to 36 eggs, 2½t salt, ¾ cup of melted butter, 3 cups of milk. The results were good, except that some butter dropped out as the eggs cooled during service.
Do I need to increase all ingredients on the ratio of the original recipe if I'm attempting to increase production for added guests?

Is the melted butter stirred into the eggs, or poured in first to grease the dish?  If it's greasing the dish, you might not need to increase it like everything else

Great point, Joe. The melted butter is poured into the cooking vessel prior to pouring eggs into it. The vessel is not changing, only the quantity of eggs-salt-milk is changing. So today I used the original amount of butter with the increased amount of eggs-salt-milk. Far less drop-out this time around. Thank you.
